# Multiple definition error when importing c++23 standard library module in multiple files

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules, c++23

I was trying out the c++23 Standard Library Modules (P2465R3) with Visual Studio 17.8.0 Preview 1.0.

When using just the one file everything works as expected and the following compiles and runs:

```cpp
// main.cpp
import std;

int main() {
    std::print("Hello Modules\n");
}
```

But once I try to use multiple files I get a linker error:

```cpp
// test.ixx
export module test;

import std;

export void do_test() {
    std::print("test\n");
}


// main.cpp
import std;
import test;

int main() {
    std::print("Hello Modules\n");
    do_test();
}
```

`LNK2005  "class std::basic_string_view<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > $S3" ?$S3@@3V?$basic_string_view@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@A) already defined in main.obj`

Is this the expected behavior? And if so, how would I go about importing the standard library modules in multiple files?

EDIT:
I noticed that I still get the link error even if I replace `import std;` with `import <print>;` in both `main.cpp` and `test.ixx`, so this is probably an issue with modules as a whole and not just the Standard Library Modules.

Comment: Maybe the answer is in the question? "Preview 1.0"

Comment: I had similar problems. Evidently, `import std` does not play well with other modules that import header files individually. I had `import <iostream>`, etc., in many of the files. When I switched them all to `import std`, things settled down.

Comment: Sadly, I still found MSVC support for C++20 modules as too buggy to be usable. This has been more than one year that I am trying to upgrade our company C++ code base to use modules, and I always see new problems (compilers internal errors). I already filled several bug reports to Microsoft, but I am getting bored with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only begun using `import std` very recently, so I cannot say for sure, but the problem may be with the implementation of `std::print`, rather than modules in general.

At first, I ran the test program exactly as you wrote it. That gave me the same link error as you got. When I eliminated `std::print` from your test program, however, replacing it with `std::cout << std::format`, the program ran fine.

###### This version uses a module for `main.ixx`:

```cpp
// main.ixx
export module main;

import std;
import test;

export int main() {
    std::cout << std::format("Hello Modules\n");
    //std::print("Hello Modules\n");
    do_test();
}
```

```cpp
// test.ixx
export module test;

import std;

export void do_test() {
    std::cout << std::format("test\n");
    //std::print("test\n");
}
```

###### I also tested without making a module for `main`:

```cpp
// main.cpp
import std;
import test;

int main() {
    std::cout << std::format("Hello Modules\n");
    //std::print("Hello Modules\n");
    do_test();
}
```

```cpp
// test.ixx
export module test;

import std;

export void do_test() {
    std::cout << std::format("test\n");
    //std::print("test\n");
}
```

Both versions ran correctly.

My experiments with `import std` have generally gone well. They are still at the experimental stage, involving roughly a dozen different modules I have coded. At first, a few of the modules imported individual Standard Library headers, with statements such as `import <vector>`, and so on. Those did not play well with the modules that used `import std`. There were weird errors akin to the linker error you encountered. When I switched everything to `import std`, those errors went away, and it has been clear sailing ever since.

It is a real plus not to have to figure out over and over again which header file needs to be included where. That alone has left me with a positive feeling about the progress being made with modules.

Comment: That does the trick, thank you! I got so used to `print`, I didn't even consider going back to `cout`. But being able to use modules definitely wins out here.